# Flink on Kubernetes: how to submit jobs to session clusters?

Tags: apache-flink

I've followed [Flink session cluster on Kubernetes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html#flink-session-cluster-on-kubernetes) to have a session cluster up and running. But then, how do I submit jobs to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to expose the JobManager REST API via a Service (or even Ingress) and use it to submit your Jobs [1] (two step process: first upload the jar, then run the jar). You can use the CLI and point it to your JobManager (-m ).

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Konstantin

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/monitoring/rest_api.html#api